# In snowflake how to get the date as i wanted format in snowflake

Tags: stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, date-format, leading-zero

I have been facing the issue while retrieving year from snowflake table.

My table has value as below:

```
year :20
day:10
month :02
```

I need to dob value as *2020-10-02*. When I am using the `concat_ws` I'm getting expected result, however the padded with *00* the dob printed like *0020-10-02*.

Also when we have *99* in the year column then while retrieving it should display *1999*

I have created query as below:

```
select to_date('concat_ws('-',json:year::varchar,json:month::varchar,json:date::varchar)', 'MM/DD/YYYY') from XXX;
```

Suggest me if any functions also.

Comment: Hello @Kannan, welcome to SO. The best way of saying _thanks_ is is to accept and up-vote the best answers. Excessive _thanks_ after each paragraph is adding noise in the real question. Please have a look on this [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021/792178)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this

```
YY

Two-digit year, controlled by the TWO_DIGIT_CENTURY_START session parameter, e.g. when set to 1980, values of 79 and 80 parsed as 2079 and 1980 respectively.

select TO_DATE('99-10-02','YY-MM-DD');
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to have automagically the "right" year display before, if some of your users are going to be very young and others very old, how could you know for sure if the person was born in 20th or 21st century?

I didn't quite get how your data is stored, so I'll assume a json structure since it appears in your query.

```
set json = '{
    "elements": [{
        "year": "01",
        "month": "02",
        "day": "10"
    }, {
        "year": "99",
        "month": "02",
        "day": "10"
    }, {
        "year": "20",
        "month": "02",
        "day": "10"
    }]
}'::varchar;
```

Now I'll parse the json, extract the values, putting that here so you can make sure we're having the same data structure.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TEMP TABLE test AS
select t2.VALUE: day::varchar   dob_day,
       t2.VALUE: month::varchar dob_month,
       t2.VALUE: year::varchar  dob_year
from (select parse_json($json) as json) t,
     lateral flatten(input => parse_json(t.json), path => 'elements') t2
```

Now is the part that will interest you. It is dirty trick and assumes that if the two digit year is higher than the current two digit year, then it cannot be 2000, but instead 1900.

```
SELECT to_date(concat_ws('-',
                         IFF(t2.dob_year > RIGHT(extract(year, current_timestamp), 2), '19'||t2.dob_year , '20'||t2.dob_year ),
                         t2.dob_month,
                         t2.dob_day)) proper_date
FROM test t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the date format in your `to_date` to `'YY-MM-DD'` should give you DOB you want, and I suggest to use `try_to_date` if you suspect data issues as it will `NULL` the field if not a valid date.

**NOTE** if you are using US formatting then use YY-DD-MM (the month in the end)

```
select to_date('concat_ws('-',json:year::varchar,json:month::varchar,json:date::varchar)', 'YY-MM-DD') from XXX;
```

Also, if you want to safely check that the DOB is not in future then add `IFF` as follows

```
IFF(CURRENT_DATE > to_date('concat_ws('-',json:year::varchar,json:month::varchar,json:date::varchar)', 'YY-MM-DD'), to_date('concat_ws('-',json:year::varchar,json:month::varchar,json:date::varchar)', 'YY-MM-DD'),NULL);
```